# Big O notation log(n^2) = O(log(n))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Hi I was wandering if log(n^2) can be written as O(log(n))?

I'm quite confused because n^2 is not O(n) but in this case since it's bounded by log, could we say that?

Comment: we have a [X Y problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `log(n^2) = 2*log(n)`, so `O(log(n ^2)) = O(2*log(n))`.  Complexity calculations cancel out all constant multiplying factors, so `O(2*log(n)) = O(log(n))`.

Comment: IMHO, this is an honest confusion which may happen to other people as well. Down-votes are not called for. Peter's answer is enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic mathematical property of logarithms:   `log(n^2) = 2*log(n)` where `^` represents "to the power of".

So `O(log(n^2)) = O(2*log(n))`.

With complexity calculations, the focus is on convergence behaviour in the limit, so constant multipliers are cancelled out.   This means `O(2*log(n)) = O(log(n))`.

Putting all the above together, the result is that `O(log(n^2)) = O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 3):

Due to log rules, log(n^2)=2log(n).